# Display month from number in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to show that if you type something for the month it displays the month
such as `january=1`, `february=2` , `march=3` ...

and year `2012`,`2013`,`2014`...

but if you type something greater than `12` for the month than it should tell you `"sorry"` and I can't figure out how to make the message work.

```
echo " please type a number for a month"
read month
echo " please type a number for a year"
read year

if [ "$month" = "1-12" ]
then
        cal "$month" "$year"
        sleep 2
        echo " thank you, good bye... "
else
        echo " sorry "  
        sleep 2
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ $month -lt 13 && $month -gt 0  ]]  
then
        cal "$month" "$year"
        sleep 2
        echo " thank you, good bye... "
else
        echo " sorry "  
        sleep 2
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It is safer to allow cal to verify the integrity of the input.

```
cal $month $year 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo sorry
fi
```

This will take care of inputs that are not integers as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
read -r -p 'please type a number for a month: ' month
read -r -p 'please type a number for a year: ' year
cal "$month" "$year" 2&>1 1>/dev/null && \
    { cal "$month" "$year" ; echo ' thank you, good bye... ' ; } || \
    echo ' sorry '
```

- read can prompt for you, no need for echo
- cal return status tells you whether it's going to work

Answer (score 0):

To test the value just use logical and for two arithmetic conditions:

```
if (( month >= 1 )) && (( month <= 12 )) ; then
    cal $month $year
else
    echo Sorry.
fi
```